# Swift Package Manager - Swift 4 syntax

Tags: swift, swift4, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to use updated SPM for Swift4 with the following `Package.swift` file - [PackageDescription API Version 4](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/swift-4.0-branch/Documentation/PackageDescriptionV4.md)

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Name",
    dependencies : [
        .package(url: "url", .branch("swift4"))
    ],
    exclude: ["Tests"]
)
```

I have a correct version of SPM also:

> Apple Swift Package Manager - Swift 4.0.0-dev (swiftpm-13081.9)

But I can not build the library by `swift build` command. I see the following error:

> ... error: type 'Version' has no member 'branch'

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're missing the tools version specifier in your manifest; add the following as the first line of your `Package.swift`:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.0
```

By default if that line is omitted, it'll default to manifest version 3 and also compiler version 3. For more information see [SE-0152](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0152-package-manager-tools-version.md) or [Swift Package Manager Manifest API Redesign](https://swift.org/blog/swift-package-manager-manifest-api-redesign/) on swift.org.

Comment: Putting an essential variable in a comment? 