# Package.Dependency has no member Package

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on my app, and I keep getting this error when I add a package so I can import it.

```
error: type 'Package.Dependency' has no member 'Package'
```

This is my Package.swift code:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.0
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "xHelp",
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/onevcat/Hedwig.git",
                 majorVersion: 1)
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "xHelp",
            dependencies: ["Hedwig"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "xHelpTests",
            dependencies: ["xHelp"]),
        ]
)
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44483929/swift-package-manager-swift-4-syntax?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) SO post, but it didn't work. What should I do here?

Comment: What is your Deployment Target?

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura/issues/1149) your issue?

Comment: Please check the swift-tools-version 4.0 syntax. .Package should be .package(). read this link: https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/PackageDescriptionV4.md

Comment: @RajeevMehta I believe iOS 11.2 but I have CocoaPods that has a target of iOS 8.0.

Comment: @Skywalker I have tried that, but that did nothing.

Comment: @razib-mollick I tried that, and I got this: https://pastebin.com/J08CEXRd

Comment: I just tried and it is working, Use this code:
.package(url: "https://github.com/onevcat/Hedwig.git",
                 from: "1.0.0")

Comment: In case if you like to use **majorVersion**, use **upToNextMajor**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should write it like this.

```
.package(url: "https://github.com/onevcat/Hedwig.git", from: "1.0.0"),
```

Comment: specially because of this limitaions: // swift-tools-version:4.0
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was getting an error like: `type 'Target.Dependency' has no member 'package'`. The issue was, I was putting the package declaration within the Target dependency, rather than the top level Package dependency.

Wrong Package.swift:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "PackageName",
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "PackageName",
            dependencies: [.package(
                    url: "https://github.com/jpsim/Yams.git",
                    from: "1.0.1")]
        )
    ] 
)
```

**FIXED**:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "PackageName",
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
        .package(
            url: "https://github.com/jpsim/Yams.git",
            from: "1.0.1")
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "PackageName",
            dependencies: []
        )
    ]
)
```

Comment: gracias - was off the same path as you.

Answer (score 1):

Everything its okay only change capital P to p in

> .Package(url: "https://github.com/onevcat/Hedwig.git",
>                    majorVersion: 1)

to lowercase

> .package(url: "https://github.com/onevcat/Hedwig.git",
>                    majorVersion: 1)